# How to configure NGINX and Nodejs App to accept requests from different domains with CNAME records

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain, cname, infrastructure

I want to build a similar solution like Mailchimp Landing Pages with Connected Sub Domain.

The summarized steps to do that is like the following (considering you already have Mailchimp account and Domain property):

https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-domain/

1. Add subdomain you want to connect on Mailchimp settings;

```
sub.domain.com
```

2. Add a CNAME record for that subdomain on your DNS provider;

```
sub.domain.com     CNAME     usXXXXXXXXXX.pages.mailchi.mp
```

3. Click on connect and wait;

With that, you can have a SSL secured subdomain pointing to another Mailchimp SSL secured subdomain with only a CNAME record, working for different origin domains:

```
https://sub.domain1.com/lp1  ->  https://usXXXX.pages.mailchi.mp  ->  backend  ->  Landing Page 1
https://sub.domain1.com/lp2  ->  https://usXXXX.pages.mailchi.mp  ->  backend  ->  Landing Page 2

https://sub.domain2.net/lp3  ->  https://usYYYY.pages.mailchi.mp  ->  backend  ->  Landing Page 3
https://sub.domain2.net/lp4  ->  https://usYYYY.pages.mailchi.mp  ->  backend  ->  Landing Page 3
```

But what isn't clear to me are the following questions:

1. How to configure this setup with many NGINX's needed using SSL all the way?
2. For this to work there is only HTTP Server configuration or I need the backend to do things too?
3. How would the scheme of that setup be?
4. I need to automate NGINX configuration, like creating vhosts on the fly and reloading it for each new customer or that can be done with regex/config?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am trying to figure this out on an Apache server but maybe you could give me some general idea about your solution that I could apply for Apache. Any thoughts?